# exponential random variable about light bulbs

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

You have three light bulbs, and their lifetimes $T_{i}$ are exponential random variables with parameters$ \lambda_{i} =i$, for $i = 1,2,3$ respectively. 
We switch on bulbs at time zero.

Find

1. the mean time you have to wait until at least one of the bulb burns out
2. the mean time you have to wait until all of the bulb burn out.
3. P( exactly two bulbs are burnt out at time $t$ ).

the last one it should be
$$
\mathrm{p}\left(t_{1}\ \mbox{and}\ t_{2} < t,\ t_{3} > t\right)\ +\
\mathrm{p}\left(t_{2}\ \mbox{and}\ t_{3} <t,\ t_{1} > t\right)\ +\
\mathrm{p}\left(t_{1}\ \mbox{and}\ t_{3} < t,\ t_{2} > t\right)
$$
but how to calculate it ?.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the lightbulb lifetimes are independently distributed

with $P(T_i \le t) = 1-e^{-\lambda_it}$ and $P(T_i \gt t) = e^{-\lambda_it}$

so your calculation for (3) is $\left(1-e^{-\lambda_1t}\right)\left(1-e^{-\lambda_2t}\right)e^{-\lambda_3t} + \left(1-e^{-\lambda_1t}\right)e^{-\lambda_2t}\left(1-e^{-\lambda_3t}\right) + e^{-\lambda_1t}\left(1-e^{-\lambda_2t}\right)\left(1-e^{-\lambda_3t}\right)$

which here seems to be

$e^{-t} +e^{-2t} - e^{-3t} -2e^{-4t} -2e^{-5t} +3e^{-6t}$